Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure in windows10
I am using jdk-22 with the same web driver & chrome driver v128.0.6613.84 with CFT with last selenium v4.23.1 but still have this problem
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-M6L1F2H', ip: '192.168.1.104'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:563)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:245)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
    at SeleniumBasics.LunchBrowser.main(LunchBrowser.java:21)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.23.1', revision: '656257d8e9'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '22.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    ... 6 more

I used this code
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.drive", "C:\\Program Files\\Testing\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions cop = new ChromeOptions();
        cop.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe");
        cop.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        cop.addArguments(new String[] { "--ignore-certificate-errors" });
        cop.setBrowserVersion("128.0.6613.84");
        cop.setCapability("browserVersion", "128.0.6613.84");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingPort(7).build(),cop);
        driver.manage().wait(time);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");


I tried to use the old Selenium version, use the free port of the system, and added the program to the ports allowed by Windows Defender for the IDE & driver and Chrome for Testing. Adding JUnit4, but still the same error.
How can I solve this problem please?

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cop); oughta do it.  No need to set port, or start a service... ChromeDriver's constructor will do that. (driverservice is not WebDriver... )

some of the options you are using are out-dated, methinks.  Try first with just WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();... let the built-in manager take care of the driver/browser. Your System.setProperty has a typo... should be System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ....

I tried simple code and I fixed the typo but still the same problem.
